# Ethernet to USB adaptor will it work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hard-drive, usb, ethernet

I have a WD MYbook-live NAS drive with only one ethernet port and WD MY Passport ultra portable drive with only 1 USB port.

I want to be able to connect the passport ultra drive to my home network and make it accessible from MY cloud app on the mobile.

If i buy an ethernet to usb adapter and connect the portable drive to my home network router, will it work?

Comment: The device will require drivers.  You won't be able to connect said device to your router for that reason.

Answer (score -1):

No, you need more than a simple NIC. You need some way of serving the files on the USB disk.

You may be able to plus the USB disk into the NAS and share the file that way. Can't check as I am on my phone

Comment: whats my best option? My NAS drive have only 1 ethernet port and my portable drive have only 1 micro B male USB port. what do i need to connect the two device together and then link them u to my home router please?

Comment: If your NAS has no USB slot your choices are 1: get one that does or 2: get a router that does. Linksys used to make the NSLU2 which did exactly what you want, but it no longer exists